# Ways pass to data between a C program and a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: mysql, c, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I want to implement an algorithm that:

1. takes database objects from a Ruby on Rails application as inputs,
2. performs calculations on the inputs,
3. queries the Rails database based on the calculations,
4. and produces an ordered set of results based on the queries.

I am going to write the algorithm in C (maybe Objective-C?) for two reasons: 1) to practice C and 2) because C is faster than Ruby.

What's the best way to query the Rails database (SQLite for development and MySQL for production) and pass the C program's output back to the Rails app?

Comment: I'd rather not query database from C-code. That's unnecessary complexity. C can calculate things quickly? Then use it for calculations only.

Comment: I'd use SQL to query the database...

Comment: If you need doc on how to make Ruby and C communicate : http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9, tab `Contents/Extract`, bottom : Free Content, Extending Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RubyInline[1] to write C code within Ruby code.  You could also create an extension [2].

[1] http://rubyinline.rubyforge.org/RubyInline/

[2] http://blog.jcoglan.com/2012/07/29/your-first-ruby-native-extension-c/